# Exclude characters from [ ] group regex, while still looking for characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match all the words that do not contain letter `l`. I tried this:

```
[a-z^k]+
```

But apparently `^` only works right behind `[`. If it was just letter `l`, I guess this would do:

```
[a-km-z]+
```

Of course apart from the fact that it just treats `l`-words as two words:

[image: image description]

But this is not the real concern, the question remains just as in title:

**Q:** How do I search for list of characters, but exclude another list of characters?

Comment: Some regex flavours allow character class substraction, some *don't*. Please tag your question with your programming language

Comment: @Mariano I added javascript, but I was hoping to get cross platform answer or a list of options.

Comment: @TomášZato: There is no fully language-agnostic solution for character set subtraction, barring for manually specifying the character ranges after subtraction. In flavors supporting look-ahead, you can do `(?![^disallowedset])[allowedset]`

Comment: @nhahtdh there's a double negative in your comment which results in just the opposite. It should be `(?=[^disallowedset])[allowedset]` :-)

Comment: @Mariano: You are right, I was going for `(?![disallowedset])[allowedset]`. Yours also works.

Comment: FWIW, [tag:.net] implements [character class substraction](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html), and [tag:java] and [tag:Ruby] implement [character class intersection](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `\b` word boundary to make sure that the match doesn't start and end within words.

```
\b[a-km-z]+\b
```

Alternatively, you can create an exclusion list using lookahead.

```
\b(?:(?![l])[a-z])+\b
```

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/17)

Comment: Well, but you anwered problem I tackled but wasn't really posting about. The problem is that I want real exclusion list, or answer reliably explaining why it's not possible.

Comment: I stressed this even harder in my question.